# Encounter the symbol when expecting one of the following in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have below procedure where I am getting error as `'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:;'`. This error is occurring at the line after the commit statement.

I am quite new to writing procedures so I am not really understanding where the issue occurs. Also there might be an issue in the insert using the select query as I am outputting data from a cursor and also I am using a select query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
IS
TST VARCHAR2(4000):= NULL;
IN_SEQ_NO NUMBER;

CURSOR C_DB IS
 SELECT NAME, ID
    from REC_PROC;

BEGIN

select IDH_SEQ.nextval INTO IN_SEQ_NO from dual;   

COMMIT;

END LOOP;

END TEST;
```

Comment: There should not be a  a space between : and = in  `IN_NESS_DB_LINK : = NESSOFT_DB.DATABASE_LINK`. Infact, there are multiple places where u need to  correct it .

Comment: thanks i have remove unwanted space not but i am getting error msg now after commit statement as Error(83,17): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:     ;

Comment: I assume you are getting compile time error. If yes then I observer few things. 1. variable NESS_QUERY is not declared. 2. In Cursor multiple alias are used - D.SYS_DB_NAME, D.ENTITY_ID, T.DAY_ID, DB.DATABASE_LINK. But cursor is selecting only from one table that is also without alias

Comment: Also 3. IN_SEQ_NO should be referred outside quotes while building insert statement.

Comment: `NESSOFT_DB.NES_FROM_TO_DATE` - there is no such column in the cursor declaration.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is very hard to get right. Why make it even tougher by including commented-out code in the generated statement? You have some kind of compilation bug. It's unlikely we're going to spot it so you need to fix this yourself. Tidy up the code. If that doesn't solve start with a smaller statement. Get that working then extend it. Iterate until you have a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `FOR rec IN C_DB LOOP` instruction to your procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
IS
    TST       VARCHAR2(4000):= NULL;
    IN_SEQ_NO NUMBER;

    CURSOR C_DB IS
    SELECT NAME,
           ID
      FROM REC_PROC;

BEGIN
    FOR rec IN C_DB
    LOOP
        SELECT IDH_SEQ.nextval INTO IN_SEQ_NO from dual;   
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END TEST;
```

or remove `END LOOP;`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
IS
    TST       VARCHAR2(4000):= NULL;
    IN_SEQ_NO NUMBER;

    CURSOR C_DB IS
    SELECT NAME,
           ID
      FROM REC_PROC;

BEGIN
    SELECT IDH_SEQ.nextval INTO IN_SEQ_NO from dual;   
    COMMIT;
END TEST;
```